# Disable images in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

I want to save some bandwidth for my mobile data plan, is there a way I can disable loading images for Google Chrome, the way I can for Opera Mini for example?

I couldn't find an option in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_for_Android) mentions that this feature exists, but I can't seem to find it in either [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) nor in [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta).

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia links to GSM Arena about this, but they don't mention how to find the setting either.

Comment: @sashoalm I'm thinking maybe Google removed the feature in the latest versions (if it really did exist as mentioned in Wikipedia).

Comment: I don't see anything in `chrome://flags` either.

Answer (score 2):

It did exist in an earlier version I was using late 2013..but as of the current release, the option has disappeared.